# VirtualBox: Can't reach local server on localhost within the guest VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, java

I'm running an Ubuntu VM. In it I have a Java server listening on a specific port within the VM. I'm trying to connect a client (also within the VM) by using `localhost`, but it can't find it.

It works fine if run on a real machine. VM is set up with a NAT Network Setting on the VM.

I also tried pinging `localhost` and I got `127.0.0.1`. I tried using that instead of `localhost` without any luck.

[image: ping command]

[image: netstat command]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the output of "ifconfig" - it sounds to me like, for whatever reason, you do not have the "lo" network device setup

Comment: Looking at your netstat I can only see java listening on IPv6, not on IPv4. So instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 you should use ::1 or change java to also listen to localhost on IPv4.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)